# AJAXIFY WordPress Theme Frontend menu

Tags: theme-development, ajax, front-end

I have the next code in my functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_frontendscript');

function my_frontendscript() {
    //registering script
    wp_register_script('frontendscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/frontend.js', array("jquery"), '1.0',  true);
    //enqueuing script
    wp_enqueue_script('frontendscript');
    //localizing javascript
    //creating ajax_object and insert it into the frontendscript
    wp_localize_script('frontendscript', 'ajax_object', 
        array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'action' => 'my_action'
        )
    );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action','my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action','my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback($text){

    echo "my action callback - success: ".$text;
    die();
}
```

And this is my frontend.js:

```
//insert the following javascript code to frontendscript.js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action  : ajax_object.action
    };

    $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        console.log('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

I understand the wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action; but I still don't know how to "ajaxify" my wordpress theme.

What can I do yo return the content page in my functions.php?

Anybody has some code example to what I want?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something like [Ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) or the [Ajaxify Wordpress Site plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/)? If your knowledge of Wordpress ajax is limited, you'd probably be better off with an existing solution

Comment: @brianjohnhana Yes, I tried with this and works well... But I would love to know how to do that "manually". Thanks for comment